# prestashop get product information on category list

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

I have many product categories in my store and some of them don't have products. I would like to erase the link on them, so the user can see them but wouldn't lose time exploring categories without products.

However I can't manage to get the number of products in the category. I've tried this but it gives me a 403 error

```
$.get('/themes/theme/product.tpl', function(r){
    var obj = $(r).find('body');
    var PageText = $(r).find('.center_indent').text();
    if (PageText===""){alert("yes")}
    else {alert("no")}
});
```

Does anyone have an idea? I'm working with prestashop 1.6.1.9

Edit: I found out I couldn't make an array of subcategories, so I added a function in the Category class:

```
public static function countProductInCat($id_category)
{
    $category = new Category($id_category, 1);
    $productCount = $category->getProducts(1, 1, 10000, null, null, true);
    return $productCount;
}
```

And I called it in the category-description.tpl file:

```
{if (Category::countProductInCat($subcategory_id)) > 0}
      <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($subcategory.id_category,$subcategory.link_rewrite)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"></a>                                                             
{else}
    <span style="opacity:0.3;background:#999"></span>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know which template you want to modify, but if you have access to a `category` object in Smarty (be it a single category or within a loop), you could test the presence of products this way :

```
{if count($category->getProducts()) > 0}
    {link .....}
{else}
    {$category->getName()}
{/if}
```

Comment: I've tried putting this in category-description but it gives me a server error.

Comment: What is the template you modify?

Comment: category-description.tpl. I tried this

    {foreach from=$subcategories item=subcategory}
        {if count($subcategory->getProducts()) > 0}
           <a class="category" href="{$link->getCategoryLink($subcategory.id_category, $subcategory.link_rewrite)}"></a>
        {else}
              <div class="category" style="opacity:0.4"></div>
         {/if}

Comment: Afaik `category-description.tpl` isn't issued in the standard theme. You might need to modify the controller to ensure that `$subcategories` is indeed an array of `Category` objects. I think you may have a 500 because you're trying to access object properties on a non object.